# How to fix Widget is disposed errer when tryng to open Shell for the second time?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

When I'm trying to open for the second time a child-shell, occur Widget is disposed error.
I'm trying to create a main Shell and, with menu-bar then child-shell for the functions.

Here the printStackTrace:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.close(Unknown Source)
at it.anabasibdg.viste.Main$2.widgetSelected(Main.java:108)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at it.anabasibdg.viste.Main.open(Main.java:51)
at it.anabasibdg.viste.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

Here the code:

```
MenuItem mntmInserimento = new MenuItem(menu_2, SWT.NONE);
    mntmInserimento.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            if(cs1.isDisposed() == false) {


            cs1.layout();
            cs1.open();




        }else {

            cs1.open();



        }
    }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a Shell has been closed the Shell and all the controls it contains are disposed and can't be used again.

You must create a new shell and all its contents from scratch each time you want to use it.